# How can I restore my C#variables that are binded to the resp. ASP.NET razor page, after I leave the chtml page and navigate to the page back again?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

Hello I have following razor page in my Blazor project that is showing the eventlog data from a remote machine. The eventlog data is read in the respective .cs file with a C# code. The C# arrays are visualised then in the table rows.
If a press the read button i get the eventlog data from the remote PC without problem.
If I navigate then to another page and navigate back to my eventlog page again i get an empty table. That means the eventlog data (C# arrays) have been lost. I want, that the last read eventlog data is still available on the page, without reading it from the machine again.
The reason is that the reading from remote PC takes a little bit long due to WMI (15-20 seconds). If the client needs each time fresh data of course he should press read button again, but if the last read data is OK for him,I want to offer him this data. How is this possible?

```
@page "/wmi_event"

<head>   
</head>
<h1>EventLog (Win Application Errors)</h1>

<body>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Read_EventLog">Read</button>
<p>Raed Time= @Read_time</p>

<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Log Time</td>
        <td>Log Source</td>
        <td>Log Message</td>
    </tr>
    @{
        for (var i = 0; i < 999; i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@Eventlog_time[i]</td>
            <td>@Eventlog_source[i]</td>
            <td>@Eventlog_message[i]</td>
        </tr>
        }

    }

</table>
</body>
```

Comment: You could save it in Local Storage or Session Storage, depending on how long you want this data to survive.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the event log into a scoped service as a property which you then inject and reference on the page.

The below has a guide on this for each type of Blazor app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#in-memory-state-container-service-wasm

Comment: Note the guide explains how to set the data from the page, so you could do that with your current code, or move the Read_EventLog call to a method in the class and handle it there.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe this data is emptied when reloading the page.

Comment: Transient service will reload with the page, scoped will reload with the session - Blazor Server

Comment: Scoped services are restarted on page refresh, it is bound to circuit connection.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine is correct, need to use `ProtectedLocalStorage` or `ProtectedSessionStorage` for this kind of persistance.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I have learned that I can do this the best way with SignalR in ASP.NET Core. Additionally, I saw that Blazor has this SignalR mechanism by default. So I switched to Blazor and it was really very easy. I suggest everyone who is not developing deep applications with Blazor to use it for these kind of issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).